# Demo Game Racing Game crashs (GamerServicesNotAvailableException)

Tags: c#, xna

I want to test the demo game Racing Game, but after a few seconds it crashs with `GamerServicesNotAvailableException`. I don't know what I have to do. Game Studio and Games for Windows LIVE is installed, what do I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in this as well as I am just getting started with XNA.  Just to cover bases, have you checked that none of the conditions listed under the help for the [GamerServicesNotAvailableException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.gamerservicesnotavailableexception.aspx) are true?

Is this your development machine, or is it a secondary test machine?  Aaron Stebner also discusses possible causes of GamerServicesNotAvailableException in his post '[Introduction to Windows game deployment features in XNA Game Studio 3.0 and 3.1](https://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/10/31/9027445.aspx)' - which also takes the cake for the longest blog post title i've seen in a long time! :)

If you find out the problem, please post here!

Thanks!
Z

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking the [XNA forums](http://forums.xna.com), there seems to be some related info in [this post](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/7604.aspx).